# Can I safely store a totally random string (any 16-bit value) into a SQLiteDB?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've got a string which I created with a custom cipher, which can have any `char` value (0 through 0xFFFF). This string is created by taking an input plaintext and rotating each character by a pseudorandom value, so I have no control over what the output characters might be.

Can I safely store and retrieve this exactly without any issues into a SQLiteDatabase `TEXT` field?

I'm think that Java uses UTF-16, so I'm somewhat afraid of chars like `NULL`, `END OF TEXT`, `ESCAPE`, `'`, `"`, `0xfeff / 0xfffe (BOM)` etc appearing in random places into my string, and I'm not really sure how SQLite will store this internally. If it uses any text-based markers to determine the start and end of fields I'm afraid this will fail.

Ideally I'd like to get back out the exact same character sequence I put in, so that I can put it through the reverse cipher.

I will be using the managed `insert(ContentValues)` method of `SqLiteDatabase`, so I think that this would take care of any issues regarding escaping the input string, but I'm still not quite convinced that this can work.

Is this a safe operation, and if not, what else should I do instead to store my encrypted string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid a Cryptographically weak custom cypher that also causes you problems, instead use Java's built in capabilities which can provide you with a cryptographically strong string.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#CipherClass

Answer (score 1):

A simple and safe way to put String into the database that you are not sure if it will always work that I can think on top of my mind is to get the byte array:

### void put(String key, byte[] value)

### byte[]   getAsByteArray(String key)

You can convert it to base64 string if you really need to store it as String (but why?) and get it back decoded.

That being said, you shouldn't need to do any of those because for the insert function, it should do the escaping for you if you use ContentValues.

ContentValue uses [Parcel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) to do type changes

Comment: Actually even thinking about escaping is making me worry a bit, as if one of my input characters is *already* escaped, SQL might unescape it on retrieval, thus corrupting the original data. Base64 sounds like a potentially good way to go.

Comment: I'm not an expert on "bytes", but is it possible that using bytes should work just as well? since nothing will really be escaped there and the only conversion is byte<->string. (a byte is a byte? :) )

Answer (score 1):

It would be safest to store it as a "blob" -- pretty much identical to a string, only with a separately-specified length.

C strings are generally assumed to be null-terminated.

Comment: That's probably a good idea, I didn't know that blob had separate length field (that would be the only way I could think of to safely delimit it).

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, strings must not contain end-of-string markser, i.e, characters with value zero.

However, you can store binary data as a blob.
This would look something like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = ...;
byte[] binaryData = ...;
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("mycolumn", binaryData);
db.insert("mytable", null, values);

Cursor cursor = db.query("mytable", new String[]{"mycolumn"}, ...);
byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
```

Comment: Yep, this is the purpose of "blob" -- to store binary (non-character) data.  Much simpler than a kluge using escaping or Base64.